# Checkbox column in grid value state

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

No matter what I try it just wont pick the value as 1 = checked.

Is there any other way to pick the checked checkbox value and pas it to function _monitoringcheck

```
Private Sub dgv2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv2.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    Dim _idTabele As Long

    If bsDgv3.Position >= 0 And bsDgv3.Position < Dgv3.Rows.Count Then
        _idTabele = Me.Dgv3.Rows(bsDgv3.Position).Cells("dgv3_id").Value
    End If

    If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "chkStatus" Then
        Dim strValue As Integer
        If dgv2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "chkStatus" Then
            Try
                strValue = Me.dgv2.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
            Catch ex As Exception
                strValue = 0
            End Try
            cl._MonitoringCheck(Math.Abs(CInt(strValue)), _idTabele)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Even if i include the "dirty check "

```
  Sub dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Dgv3.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If Dgv3.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        Dgv3.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. I see you have If dgv2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "chkStatus" Then - Are you checking to see if the column is true or false or just when it is clicked on?

Comment: When you debug it, what does dgv2.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value equal?  Is that Try/Catch catching? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: Try catch is catching it as 0 it doesnt go to exception.
@codeMonger123 yes when its clicked on it i just  want to read is it checked or not.